# Fresh CentOS 7, first Laravel Installation.Composer install breaks

Tags: laravel, installation, composer-php, centos7

I am fallowing this tutorial: 
http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-laravel-php-centos-7-ubuntu-15-04/
And on step 5) when running composer install in the project directory it starts to do staff, as expected, until this happened:

```
Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined constant 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 779
PHP Fatal error:  Undefined constant 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /var/www/laravel-develop/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 779
Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

What is the problem?
Thanks, Aleks

Comment: try sudo composer self-update.. might solve your problem

Comment: Nothing has changed, error persists @Jaimin

Comment: Delete the compiled.php file inside the vendor folder and do a php artisan clear-compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start creating a project (after updating composer)  instead of downloading the referenced file do the following

1. from your terminal type in `cd /var/www/`
2. then type `composer create-project laravel/laravel laravel-develop`
3. your composer should download the latest version of Laravel

try it this way feel free to ask any questions.
Good Luck